# Переход на фреймворк

Tags: php, framework, seo, redirect

Есть сайт, написанный процедурно и с устаревшими подходами в PHP. Сейчас я хочу полностью переписать его на фреймворке Laravel. Кто занимался подобным? Много ли подводных камней?

Еще вопрос, каким образом сделать правильный редирект в `htaccess` для поисковиков и скорейшей правильной переиндексаии. Старый путь:

```
http://site.com/items.php?item=356084821
```

Новый будет примерно таким:

```
http://site.com/item/356084821<br>
```

Comment: Код покрыт тестами?

Comment: Вообще смена URL-ов на сайте может очень негативно отразиться на поисковой выдаче. Поэтому если сайт коммерческий и приносит стабильный доход, то стоит задуматься о том, как сохранить все адреса. К примеру, на Yii2 можно использовать стандартные GET параметры наряду с установленным роутингом.
В любом случае выбирайте тот путь, который принесет больший эффект с меньшими потерями.

Answer (score 5):

Многие программисты бояться всего нового, ибо освоение новой технологии занимает время, лучше уж старое, но привычное, чем новое, неизведанное и не всегда лучшее. Нужно всегда развиваться и идти вперед. На нативном PHP далеко не пойдете.

Фреймворк - набор готовых функций, процедур и многого другого, создан для того, чтобы избавить программиста от рутиной работы. Практически все фреймворки построены с использованием принципов ООП и неплохо было перед разработкой с их использованием разобраться в этих трёх буквах. Использование фреймворков — это хороший шаг, который позволяется сосредоточиться на написании бизнес-логики вашего приложения, вместо реализации велосипедов.

Советую смотреть в сторону таких фреймворков, как Yii, Symfony, Laravel. Вы выбрали Laravel. Попробуйте после написания на Laravel переписать на Yii, Symfony. И сразу поймете разницу. Главное знать сам язык хорошо, а технологии всегда меняются и требуют внимания к себе. Кстати в Symfony очень хорошая маршрутизация.

---

Удачного кодинга...