# С какой версии yii начать обучение?

Tags: yii2, yii

Доброго времени суток. Есть yii1 и yii2, несложно догадаться что вторая версия должна быть лучше первой. Нужно ли изучать первую версию что бы освоить вторую или же есть способ освоить только вторую? Или все равно нужно знать первую с точки зрения знания и использования чужого кода с которым я все равно столкнусь рано или поздно? У меня опыт разработки на php минимальный, поэтому и интересуюсь данным вопросом.

Comment: Можете их расценивать как два разных фреймверка, так как изменения очень сильно затронули ядро. Подход у фреймерков одинаковый но реализации очень разные. Изучайте Yii2, если станет интересно потом гляните Yii1. Новые проэкты будут однозначно писатся на Yii2, но если Вас интересует поддержка существующих тогда Yii1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yii2** кардинально отличается от первой версии. Да и на дворе **2016** год. Зачем изучать первую версию, когда есть возможность начать с более новой и свежей версии. Но для работы с фреймворками нужно подкачать сам **PHP** и ознакомиться с паттерном **MVC**. (как минимум)

Вам нужно изучать сам **PHP** вне зависимости от фреймворка, который вы выберите. Сам лично работал и на первой версии, и на второй. Продолжаю работать на **Yii2**.

Если начинаете с нуля, то беритесь за **Yii2**, ибо смысла начинать с первой версии не вижу. Ну разве, что Вас возьмут на поддержку проекта, написанного на **Yii1**.

Comment: + лишняя инфа: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516531/180583

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть проект и вы думаете на чем его написать, я бы посоветовал yii2.

Если вы хотите именно изучить, то yii1 будет попроще, но я бы не зацикливался на ней, пробежался глазами и взялся за yii2.